# Why do I get this syntax error in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am running this code:

```
count=0
l=[1,2,3]
For i in l:
  print(count+=1)
```

This line throws a syntax error in line `print(count+=1)`.

If I use like this, it works:

```
count=0
l=[1,2,3]
For i in l:
  count+=1
  print(count)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using Python 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a `count +=1` is the same as `count = count+1`, so it doesnt make sense if you type `print(count = count + 1)` because `count` is being taken as a keyword argument in `print()`

Comment: @SenthilkumarM glad to help :), please feel free to select this as an answer.